# Go Build tag - getting timestamp on Windows

Tags: go

I have seen the following command to set build version

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.minversion `date -u +.%Y%m%d%.H%M%S`" service.go
```

but I cant get the timestamp part to work on Windows !

I am using go 1.5 with the following arguments...

```
build -i -ldflags "-X main.SERVER_NAME=MFFP -X main.VERSION=1.0.0 -X main.BUILD_DATE=`date -u +.%Y%m%d%.H%M%S`"
```

The error is with the date part

Is this error system related?
Anyone tried this on Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The command on *nix systems is using backtick command substitution. `date` is a built-in on POSIX, and anything inside `` ` ``s is interpreted as a shell command and is replaced by its value.

`cmd.exe` doesn't do command substitution inside backticks at all, There's some ways to accomplish the same thing using `for /F delims=""`, aka the most powerful command in Windows shell, but it's pretty hacky. Maybe use powershell instead, which supports the `$(command)` syntax?

```
PS C:\users\adsmith> go build -i -ldflags "-X main.SERVER_NAME=MFFP -X main.VERSION=1.0.0 -X main.BUILD_DATE=$(Get-Date -uformat .%Y%m%d%.H%M%S)"
```

You might have to play with the format -- I'm not sure what that's supposed to look like on POSIX. This outputs:

```
.20160107.111641
// Jan 7th 2016, 11:16:41
```

Comment: Ok that was what I suspected ! I tried your idea with Powershell $(Get-Date .. command but the Build tool does not like it ! I dont know how to get a trace of the Build command to see more detail on the error. For the moment the build tool just list all the availables options instead of giving me error info !

Comment: OK I figured out my problem ! Your answer was exactly on target ! I had problem because I was introducing spaces in the BUILD_Date assignement ! I was trying to use a full DateTime format that produces a string like "11 january 2016 11:00:02" and the assignement to BUILD_DATE would crash the Build command... THANK YOU !!!